# Android 6.0. Image file from gallery is created but it is empty

Tags: android

Android 6.0.

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

I want to get uri to temp file when choose image from gallery:

In my fragment:

When click choose from gallery:

```
 private void choosePhotoFromGallery() {
    Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    Uri tempUri = Uri.fromFile(getTempFile();
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempUri);
    photoPickerIntent.putExtra("outputFormat", BitmapUtil.BITMAP_COMPRESS_FORMAT.toString());
    startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, SELECT_PHOTO);
}
```

OK. When I success choose image the file **tempUri** was success created but it size = 0. So when call this method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SELECT_PHOTO && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri tempUri = Uri.fromFile(getTempFile());
        beginCrop(tempUri);
    }
}
```

is nothing to crop because file **tempUri** is exist but it is empty. This problem is only on Android 6.0+. On Android 4.0 all work fine.

Comment: Asked the user to confirm write external storage permission? Google for runtime permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On Android 4.0 all work fine.

Perhaps it works on one device that you tried. There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models. Those will ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of different apps that offer `ACTION_PICK` for the `MediaStore` content.

And, for most of those devices, your code is making invalid assumptions:

- There is no `crop` extra for `ACTION_PICK`
- `ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type
- There is no `EXTRA_OUTPUT` extra for `ACTION_PICK`
- There is no `outputFormat` extra for `ACTION_PICK`
- `getTempUri()` will be meaningless for `ACTION_PICK`, at least in terms of what the user picks, as `ACTION_PICK` returns the `Uri` via the `Intent` delivered to `onActivityResult()`

The `ACTION_PICK` protocol is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK).

Now, it is entirely possible that your undocumented stuff actually works... for a few devices. You could attempt to limit the distribution of your app to only those devices... but if the user installs some other app that offers `ACTION_PICK` for the `MediaStore`, then you are still out of luck, as that app may not support your undocumented stuff.

So, get rid of the undocumented stuff, and use `data.getData()` in `onActivityResult()` to get the `Uri` to the content that the user picked.

Comment: I use this crop lib: https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop . As result my code is simple and clean.